# CollectionView with images inside a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I want a TableView with 5 CollectionViews one by one. The Collection Views must display images that scroll horizontally. I followed this tutorial: https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

But I want images scrolling in my CollectionView. I don't know how to do that.

Here is my sample code:

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController1: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var images = [UIImage(named:"banner2"),UIImage(named:"banner1"),UIImage(named:"banner3"),UIImage(named:"banner4"),UIImage(named:"banner5")]

     var storedOffsets = [Int: CGFloat]()

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 5
        } 

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! Cell2
          cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 28, width: 375, height: 202)
            cell.myCollection.reloadData()
            return cell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                guard let tableViewCell = cell as? Cell2 else { return }
                tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
                tableViewCell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[indexPath.row] ?? 0
            }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            guard let tableViewCell = cell as? Cell2 else { return }
            storedOffsets[indexPath.row] = tableViewCell.collectionViewOffset
        }
    }

extension ViewController1: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return images.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! Cell1
            cell.image.image = images[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]      
            return cell
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            print("Collection view at row \(collectionView.tag) selected index path \(indexPath)")
        }
    }


import UIKit
class Cell1: UICollectionViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
               image.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 175, height: 175) // Here I get exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0) warning
               contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            self.contentView.addSubview(image)
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)   
        }
    }

import UIKit

class Cell2: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var myCollection: UICollectionView!

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            myCollection.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 28, width: 375, height: 202)   
        }
    }

extension Cell2 {

           func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate>(_ dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

              self.myCollection.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
               self.myCollection.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
                myCollection.tag = row
                myCollection.setContentOffset(myCollection.contentOffset, animated:false) // Stops collection view if it was scrolling.
                    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
                    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
                    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: 5, right: 0)
                    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
                    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
                    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 182, height: 182)
                    myCollection = UICollectionView.init(frame: myCollection.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
                    myCollection.register(Cell1.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
                    self.contentView.addSubview(myCollection)
                myCollection.reloadData()
            }

var collectionViewOffset: CGFloat {
    set { myCollection.contentOffset.x = newValue }
    get { return myCollection.contentOffset.x }
   }
}
```

[image: My output is like this]

A pink TableView (I set the colour) and black CollectionView(Again, I set the colour) I can't view my images or my CollectionViewCells that I have set as greenColor. And when touch in the pink part or try scroll I get the error: **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** with the warning - **exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)**

Can someone tell me how I can do this?  Thanks in advance

I use Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

Comment: You need to implement `UICollectionViewDataSorce` and delegate method with `UITableViewCell` not with `ViewController1`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do that. It gives me the same output

Answer (score 0):

I have snippet  in OBJECTIVE- C , i think you have to convert into swift 3.0

Here is my code

You can try it

tablecell cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell3";
        CollectionViewTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CollectionViewTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.headerLabel.text = @"DISH TYPE";

        cell.collectionView.delegate = self;
        cell.collectionView.dataSource = self;
        cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.collectionView reloadData];
```

and collection view cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
 if(collectionView.tag == 4){
        FIPhotoCollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"foodTagCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSDictionary *dic = [arrAmenities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic1 = [selectedAmenities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[dic valueForKey:@"ImageURL"]];
            [cell.photoImage sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];


        return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Should I add the code for TableCell cellForRowAtIndexPath at my ViewController and CollectionCell cellForItemAtIndexPath at TableViewCell class? Because as you can see I have the CollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath method in my external ViewController and when I add there it shows ----if(myCollection.tag == 0)   unresolved use of identifier 'myCollection'--- Could you please explain?

Comment: @AraRose : You can try this myCollection replace with collectionView.